# How to get Picklist color value (hexadecimal value)?

Tags: picklist

Assuming we select for each picklist value a specific color (ie not dynamic assignment)
how to query the hexadecimal color value in Apex/soql ?

Comment: I haven't found any API or table through which to retrieve colour assignments for picklist values. I'll be interested to see if someone else has...

Comment: Is your choice of colors already defined? Where are you using this picklist, as a field on the object?

Comment: @CyberJus. yes each picklist value has a color. we want to use the color value as a filter in a custom component.  since we can not add new attributes in the picklist, option is either add a prefix/suffix in the api name  or label name . but for other reasons , we want to avoid this. thus i was trying to see if you could use the color as a filter if i am able to query it.

Answer (score 0):

The Metadata API looks like it has access to the charting color property of picklist values.

You would need to access the `CustomValue` metadata type.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customvalue.htm